# Prove $\lim_{x\to 2} f(x) = 3$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f(x) = \begin{cases}x^2 + 2x - 5;  &x\ne 2\\ 0 &x=2.\end{cases}$. Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to 2}f(x) = 3$.

By theorem,
$$\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x) = L \iff \lim_{x\to a+}f(x) = L = \lim_{x\to a-}f(x).$$

*Demostración:* Let $\epsilon > 0$. Note that $|x^2 +2x - 5 - 3| = |x+4||x-2|$.

Showing right hand limit. Let $0 < x-2 \le 1$. Then $|x+4| = |x-2+6| \leq 1 + 6$. Set $\delta_1 = \min\{1,\frac \epsilon 7\}$. Then if $0 < x-2<\delta_1$, this implies that $|x+4||x-2| \le 7|x-2|<\epsilon$.

Showing left hand limit. Let $-1 < x-2 < 0$. Then $|x+4| \le |x-2| + 4 < 4$. Then set $\delta_2 = \min\{1,\frac \epsilon 4\}$. Then if $-\delta_2 < x-2<0$, this implies $|x+4||x-2|\le 4|x-2|<\epsilon$.

Because the $\lim_{x\to 2+}f(x) = 3 = \lim_{x\to 2-}f(x)$, we conclude that $\lim_{x\to 2}f(x) = 3$.

I am a bit iffy on proving left hand limits. Please help.

Comment: Very surprised that anyone would downvote your answer.  I upvoted it, from $(-1)$ to $(0)$.  In fact, I would have upvoted your answer anyway, because of the significant effort that you made to show your work in attacking the problem.  From my perspective, it is irrelevant whether you have any analytical errors, or whether you got stuck at a specific point.  What is relevant is that you showed your work.

Comment: For what it's worth, the constraint that $f(x) = 0 ~: ~x = 2$ is unnecessary to attack the problem.  This is because the $\epsilon, \delta$ definition of a limit focuses on (in this problem) $0 < |x -2| < \delta$, rather than $0 \leq |x-2| < \delta$.

Comment: Re previous comment, delving into the mind of the *problem composer*, note that because $f(2) \neq 3$, you have that $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x = 2$.  Arguably, the point of the problem is that you can have that the limit as $x \to 2$ of $f(x)$ exists and equals a finite value $L$, without the function $f(x)$ being continuous at $x = 2$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $0 < |x - 2| < \delta_{\varepsilon}$. Then we have:
\begin{align*}
|f(x) - 3| & = |x^{2} + 2x - 5 - 3|\\\\
& = |x^{2} + 2x - 8|\\\\
& = |(x^{2} - 4x + 4) + (6x - 12)|\\\\
& = |(x-2)^{2} + 6(x-2)|\\\\
& \leq |x - 2|^{2} + 6|x - 2|\\\\
& < \delta^{2}_{\varepsilon} + 6\delta_{\varepsilon} := \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I am currently trying to figure out what $\delta_\epsilon$ is suppose to be. So I can just proceed with show $\lim\limits_{x\to 2}f(x) = L$ and not have to deal with left and right hand side limits?

Comment: Let $\delta_\epsilon = \min\{\frac \epsilon 4, \frac \epsilon {24}\}$? Does that work?

Comment: @user10101 In answer to your questions: [1] The definition of a limit is that $\delta$ is supposed to be based on $\epsilon$.  The answer of Átila Correia emphasized this by using the nomenclature of $\delta_\epsilon$, rather than merely $\delta$.  Also, a math problem like the one that you posted is generally attacked by focusing on the *overall* limit, rather than separately focusing on the left hand side limit and right hand side limit separately.

Comment: @user10101 Note that in general, the premise that $0 < |x - a| < \delta $ is exactly equivalent to the following two premises: [1] $x \neq a, ~\delta > 0, ~~~$ and [2] $- \delta < (x - a) < \delta$.  Then, premise [2] is itself exactly equivalent to the premise $(a - \delta) < x < (a + \delta).$

Comment: @user10101 In answer to the question that you posted in your 2nd comment above, no, that approach is not good.  What is needed is some way of establishing that $\delta^2 \leq \delta$.  This may be accomplished by requiring that $\delta \leq 1$.  Based on this approach, you also need that $7 \delta < \epsilon,$ given the final conclusion in the posted answer.  Therefore, a specification that works is $\displaystyle \delta = \min\left(1, \frac{\epsilon}{8}\right).$

Comment: I see. Thank you for helping me on this!